# Which metadata fields change when you edit a PDF file using iText?

Tags: pdf, itext, metadata, computer-forensics

Which changes would we see pertaining in the metadata of a PDF file that is being edited by iText.

Comment: Which iText versions?

Comment: We don't disclose all changes because we want it to be possible to see when a document was changed by iText so that we can detect abuse of the library. Of course: as the source code is open, it is fairly easy to vet the code to find out all the visible and invisible changes in the PDF structure and metadata.

Answer (score 1):

When editing PDFs the following (obvious) places are added - for the hidden stuff you have to check the sourcecode yourself:

1. The Producer (part of the document information dictionary, always appended to the original string) e.g.: `/Producer(Acrobat Distiller 8.2.5 \(Windows\); modified using iText® 5.4.2 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA \(AGPL-version\)`
2. The producer (part of the XMP Meta data, always appended to the original string) e.g.: `<pdf:Producer>Acrobat Distiller 8.2.5 (Windows); modified using iText 5.4.2 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA (AGPL-version)</pdf:Producer>`
3. The iText version is added after the PDF trailer: `trailer
   <</ID ...>>
   %iText-5.4.2`
4. Depending on the version - in prior versions the string `ITXT` was added